# How to get System time instead of Server time in java?

Tags: java

I want to display the current system time. I have used Date d = new Date(). In my local i am getting my system time, but after deployed, it is taking server time. How do i get system time after deployed also?

Any idea??

Comment: use javascript var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();

Comment: Can you elaborate it?

Comment: Is it a webapplication or a standalone client application ?

Comment: @0991 in web application java codes run at server side ,so you will get date of server. In order to get client time,use javascript because javascript runs at client side

Comment: @SpringLearner thanks for your answer..Working fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your java code is running on some server so obviously it will take system time or machine time where it is installed, if you want to take client machine time which you are calling system time you will have to use some scripting at <s>server</s> client side, say javascript and send it to your server for further processing.

For your requirement I suggest you can run some script on HTML page load and send it to server, where it will be stored in some temporary variable for further processing.

***[update]:*** you can use [javascript.getTime](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) to full fill your purpose and send it using [AJAX call](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you can use client side scripting language like `javascript` or using `java applets` for fetch information from client machine.